# get_images from the created folder not work in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a rookie in Codeigniter, I'm trying to do news system with photo gallery. All news should create a new directory with pictures.
Function do_upload () works and creates directories, but the function get_images () does not work. Here is my model:

```
function Mdl_tasks() {
 parent::__construct();

$this->gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH . '../images/');
$this->gallery_path_url = base_url().'images/';

}

function do_upload() {
               $this->load->helper('date');
               $folderName = now();
               $pathToUpload = $this->gallery_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $folderName;
                if ( ! file_exists($pathToUpload) ) {
                   $create = mkdir($pathToUpload, 0777);
                   $createThumbsFolder = mkdir($pathToUpload . '/thumbs', 0777);
                   if ( ! $create || ! $createThumbsFolder)
                   return;
                   }

        $config = array(
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|gif|png',
            'upload_path' => $pathToUpload,
            'max_size' => 2000,
                        'encrypt_name' => TRUE,
                        'remove_spaces' => TRUE
        );

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->do_upload();
        $image_data = $this->upload->data();
                echo 'File upload success!';
                $add['filename'] = $image_data['file_name'];
                $this->db->insert('gallery', $add);

        $config = array(
            'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
            'new_image' => $pathToUpload . '/thumbs',
            'maintain_ration' => true,
            'width' => 150,
            'height' => 100
        );

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

    }

    function get_images() {

                $this->load->helper('date');
                $folderName = now();
                $pathToUpload = $this->gallery_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $folderName;
                $pathToThupmUpload = $this->gallery_path_url . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $folderName;

        $files = scandir($pathToUpload);
        $files = array_diff($files, array('.', '..', 'thumbs'));

        $images = array();

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $images []= array (
                'url' => $pathToThupmUpload . $file,
                'thumb_url' => $pathToThupmUpload . 'thumbs/' . $file
            );
        }

        return $images;
    }
```

Any ideas why get_images() doesn't work? Thanks!

Sorry! This is my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: If this is a model you are missing extends CI_Model

Comment: I have extends CI_Model. I just did not paste the whole code because it is very long and does not apply to the gallery.

Answer (score 0):

try to change this:

```
$images = array (
     'url' => $pathToThupmUpload . $file,
      thumb_url' => $pathToThupmUpload . 'thumbs/' . $file
  );
```

Also try to print_r `$files`

Comment: I think that the paths are somewhere wrong, because in console i have this: localhost/ssf/images/thumbs/1375609645 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Do you have in your htaccess exceptions for folders ? It may be that the images/thumbs/1375609645 is passed as URI not as path to image. Also I do not see the extension of file such as .jpg .gif .png or so

Comment: This is my .htaccess file:

Comment: well you are missing file extension

Comment: I wrote the above code because they are not past 8 hours on my registration yet to write answers.

Comment: Sorry? I do not understand you

Comment: Well the problem won't be in htaccess your url of img should look like this: images/thumbs/1375609645.jpg now it is just images/thumbs/1375609645